# Selecting multiple database tables from between datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to select a database table between the range of the date selected from the datepicker on my web, my sample database table names are:

- output_11FEB2016
- output_13FEB2016
- output_15FEB2016
- output_21FEB2016

I want to select tables to show and show their contents on my web, here is my current codes from what I understand on my research.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[gen048_mLIST] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here


@gfromDate varchar(10),
@gtoDate varchar(10)


AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

declare @sql varchar(5000)

set @sql='select * output_'


if(@gfromDate<>'' and @gtoDate<>'')
begin
    set @sql=@sql+'between '+convert(datetime,'''+@gfromDate+''')+' and '+convert(datetime,'''+@gtoDate+''')+' '


--print @sql
exec(@sql)

-- [dbo].[gen048_mLIST] '2-16-2016','2-18-2016'

END
```

Sorry for my messed up codes and explanation, I appreciate those who can help me figure out my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to select the rows from multiple tables,UNION it and display it in your application.I've used hardcoded dates to generate the SQL but you can modify/extend this to suit your requirements.

```
declare @gfromDate varchar(10) = '11/02/2016'
declare @gtoDate varchar(10) = '24/02/2016'
declare @fromDate datetime
declare @toDate datetime
declare @totaldays int

set @fromDate  = (select convert (date, @gfromDate, 104))
set @toDate  = (select convert (date, @gtoDate, 104))

-- get total number of days between from and to dates
set @totaldays = (select datediff(day,@fromdate,@toDate))

declare @sql varchar(max) = ''
declare @tablename varchar(20)
declare @counter int = 1

-- generate the sql to get data from the tables within a date range
while @counter < @totaldays
begin
    set @tablename = (select convert(varchar(11), @fromDate, 106))
    set @tablename = replace(@tablename,' ','')

    -- check if table exists
    --if object_id(@tablename, 'U') is not null
    --begin
    set @sql = @sql + 'select * from output_' +  @tablename 
    if(@counter < @totaldays-1)
    begin
        set @sql = @sql + ' union '
    end
    set @fromDate = dateadd(day,1,@fromDate)
    set @counter = @counter + 1
    --end
end
print @sql
```

**SQL Generated**

```
select * from output_11Feb2016 union 
select * from output_12Feb2016 union 
select * from output_13Feb2016 union 
select * from output_14Feb2016 union 
select * from output_15Feb2016 union 
select * from output_16Feb2016 union 
select * from output_17Feb2016 union 
select * from output_18Feb2016 union 
select * from output_19Feb2016 union 
select * from output_20Feb2016 union 
select * from output_21Feb2016 union 
select * from output_22Feb2016
```